# Gear menu unavailable

Tags: theming

Haven't been on Drupal for a while and now I seem to be lost at some points. Please help me get on the right track ;-)

I decided to build a theme based on the Stark theme and found out that the contextual menu gear widget does not appear. It's definitely a theme issue, because the widget comes up for the very same block when I switch the theme to, say, Garland.

What could be the reasone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contextual links are being exposed via contextual module. just by looking into the module, you would find the function [contextual_preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!contextual!contextual.module/function/contextual_preprocess/7).

```
 $variables['title_suffix']['contextual_links'] = array(
      '#type' => 'contextual_links', 
      '#contextual_links' => $element['#contextual_links'], 
      '#element' => $element,
    );
```

So my first guess would be, that you are missing in the [block.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) or [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7), etc... templates to output the $title_suffix variable?

```
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for useful chunk of info. In my case the blocks were output rather than `rendered`.